# Check if custom URI is registered

Tags: javascript, uri, microsoft-edge

I have this issue where I have a small executable program that is installed on a client pc and is then registered to a custom URI schema `customUri:X`

However, I cannot currently find anyway to check whether this uri schema is valid and that the executable is installed from client side javascript. One note is that my application is running the Chromium-based Edge browser only, so the solutions needs to be compatible for this.

Where I get stuck is when the browser prompts that 'This website is trying to open application Y'. Here the client can press OK (and possibly check 'do this always') or Cancel. This prompt is what is ruining my timeout solutions, because it is non-blocking from the website execution.

What I need is to check if the program is launched using the custom uri, and if it is not I need to redirect the clients to my download page for the installer to said executable.

What I have tried:

- Set a timeout to redirect to the download page after changing `document.location = 'customUri:X'`
- Set a boolean if onblur has happened and then using a timeout to check this boolean

Do you have any ideas on how this can be achieved using Javascript in the Chromium-based Edge browser?

I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue on my Edge browser. And the behavior is the same in Chrome. The prompt can't be detected in JavaScript so I think you can't check if the custom uri is valid using JavaScript. In this situation, I think you can only use some backend code to check if the program is opened or if the uri schema is set correctly in registry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that my application is installed on a remote server where clients connect to it and because of this I cannot use any backend code or registry checks because everything needs to be handled client-side with javascript...
If it is not possible to perform this check I will need to find another solution...

Comment: I have no idea about other ways to check it in javascript. Let's wait and see if other community members will come up some good ideas.